# How to silence audio many intervals in middle of video using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have a long video (eg. 10 mins duration). Now I want to silence audio of this video only at these specific intervals:
- From 00:01:00 to 00:01:40
- From 00:05:30 to 00:06:10
or more intervals.
How can I do using ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1):

Basic syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i video -c:v copy -af volume=0:enable='between(t,60,100)+between(t,330,370)+between(t,465,541.3)' out.mp4
```

Times are provided in fractional seconds.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  I get `Missing ')' or too many args in 'between(t'`.

Comment: In some shells, you have to escape the commas, so `t,60` becomes `t\,60` and so on.

Comment: Ah, that works; thanks.  This works, too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29222419/513038